# ForEach TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, textfield

Let's say that I have a class `Student`

```swift
class Student: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()

    @Published var name = ""
}
```

Used within an Array in another class (called `Class`)

```swift
class Class: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()

    @Published var name = ""
    var students = [Student()]
}
```

Which is defined like this in my `View`.

```swift
@ObservedObject var newClass = Class()
```

My question is: how can I create a `TextField` for each `Student` and bind it with the `name` property properly (without getting errors)?

```swift
ForEach(self.newClass.students) { student in
    TextField("Name", text: student.name)
}
```

Right now, Xcode is throwing me this:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'TextField<Text>' to closure result type '_'
```

I've tried adding some `$`s before calling the variables, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the `@Published` into a `@State` for the Student's name property. `@State` is the one that gives you a `Binding` with the `$` prefix.

```swift
import SwiftUI

class Student: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
  var id = UUID()

  @State var name = ""
}

class Class: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
  var id = UUID()

  @Published var name = ""
  var students = [Student()]
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var newClass = Class()

  var body: some View {
    Form {
      ForEach(self.newClass.students) { student in
        TextField("Name", text: student.$name) // note the $name here
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

In general I'd also suggest to use structs instead of classes.

```swift
struct Student: Identifiable {
  var id = UUID()
  @State var name = ""
}

struct Class: Identifiable {
  var id = UUID()

  var name = ""
  var students = [
    Student(name: "Yo"),
    Student(name: "Ya"),
  ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var newClass = Class()

  var body: some View {
    Form {
      ForEach(self.newClass.students) { student in
        TextField("Name", text: student.$name)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Xcode 13 gives me this warning about this: "Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update."