# How to update attributes of a struct with TextFields made in ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, swiftui, textfield

In SwiftUI I have a list of menu items that each hold a name, price etc. There are a bunch of categories and under each are a list of items.

```swift
struct ItemList: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var picture: String
    var list: [Item]
    
    @State var newItemName: String
}
```

I was looking for a way to create a TextField inside each category that would add to its array of items.

[image]

Making the TextFields through a ForEach loop was simple enough, but I got stuck trying to add a new Item using the entered text to the right category.

```swift
ForEach(menu.indices) { i in
    Section(header: Text(menu[i].name)) {
        ForEach(menu[i].list) { item in
            Text(item.name)
        }
        TextField("New Type:", text: /*some kind of bindable here?*/) {
            menu[i].list.append(Item(name: /*the text entered above*/))
        }
    }
}
```

I considered using @Published and Observable Object like [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589725/foreach-textfield-in-swiftui), but I need the ItemList to be a Codable struct so I couldn't figure out how to fit the answers there to my case.

```swift
TextField("New Type:", text: menu[i].$newItemName)
```

Anyway any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to focus your `View`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExpandingMenuView: View {
    @State var menu: [ItemList] = [
        ItemList(name: "Milk Tea", picture: "", list: [ItemModel(name: "Classic Milk Tea"), ItemModel(name: "Taro milk tea")]),
        ItemList(name: "Tea", picture: "", list: [ItemModel(name: "Black Tea"), ItemModel(name: "Green tea")]),
        ItemList(name: "Coffee", picture: "", list: [])
        
    ]
    var body: some View {
        List{
            //This particular setup is for iOS15+
            ForEach($menu) { $itemList in
                ItemListView(itemList: $itemList)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemListView: View {
    @Binding var itemList: ItemList
    @State var newItemName: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text(itemList.name)) {
            ForEach(itemList.list) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            TextField("New Type:", text: $newItemName, onCommit: {
                //When the user commits add to array and clear the new item variable
                itemList.list.append(ItemModel(name: newItemName))
                newItemName = ""
            })
        }
    }
}
struct ItemList: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var picture: String
    var list: [ItemModel]
    //@State is ONLY for SwiftUI Views
    //@State var newItemName: String
}
struct ItemModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    
}
struct ExpandingMenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExpandingMenuView()
    }
}
```

If you aren't using Xcode 13 and iOS 15+ there are many solutions in SO for Binding with array elements. Below is just one of them

```
ForEach(menu) { itemList in
    let proxy = Binding(get: {itemList}, set: { new in
        let idx = menu.firstIndex(where: {
            $0.id == itemList.id
        })!
        menu[idx] = new
    })
    ItemListView(itemList: proxy)
}
```

Also note that using `indices` is considered unsafe. You can watch Demystifying SwiftUI from WWDC2021 for more details.

Comment: The `ForEach($menu) { $itemList in` syntax isn't iOS 15 only, it's a Swift 5.5 feature. You only need iOS 15 if using `enumerated()` on a `Binding`, for example.

Comment: Yeah that worked perfectly thanks! Had a bit of a tough time upgrading to swift 5.5, but the Binding() method worked great, really appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

You can have an `ObservableObject` to be your data model, storing categories which then store the items.

You can then bind to these items, using Swift 5.5 syntax. This means we can write `List($menu.categories) { $category in /* ... */ }`. Then, when we write `$category.newItem`, we have a `Binding<String>` to the `newItem` property in `Category`.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var menu = Menu(categories: [
        Category(name: "Milk Tea", items: [
            Item(name: "Classic Milk Tea"),
            Item(name: "Taro Milk Tea")
        ]),
        Category(name: "Tea", items: [
            Item(name: "Black Tea"),
            Item(name: "Green Tea")
        ]),
        Category(name: "Coffee", items: [
            Item(name: "Black Coffee")
        ])
    ])

    var body: some View {
        List($menu.categories) { $category in
            Section(header: Text(category.name)) {
                ForEach(category.items) { item in
                    Text(item.name)
                }

                TextField("New item", text: $category.newItem, onCommit: {
                    guard !category.newItem.isEmpty else { return }
                    category.items.append(Item(name: category.newItem))
                    category.newItem = ""
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Menu: ObservableObject {
    @Published var categories: [Category]

    init(categories: [Category]) {
        self.categories = categories
    }
}

struct Category: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var items: [Item]
    var newItem = ""
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: You may want to add the Combine import line before somebody gets confused.

Comment: @ElTomato But it's using SwiftUI, so Combine is already imported by SwiftUI

Comment: @ElTomato Why not? Give it a try yourself. Compiles perfectly fine. Do be sure you are using Swift 5.5, though. Importing Combine is redundant here.

Comment: Okay.  You are right about Combine.  I'm sorry about that.

Comment: @ElTomato nw! If you `command + click` on `import SwiftUI` then see definition, the 2nd import from SwiftUI is Combine.

Comment: Does this code need Swift 5.5?  I see two errors if I don't run with Swift 5.5.

Comment: @ElTomato Yep - see paragraph 2 in my answer. It's the new element binding syntax. See [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/#xcode-s-new-element-binding-syntax). Also, it's a Swift feature so backwards compatible for iOS versions.

Comment: Note SwiftUI does import Combine, but it does not export it, so there are (many) instances
when you also need to import Combine as well to have access to its types.

Comment: @workingdog Ah that's true because they are both Swift frameworks. Nonetheless, this example works without `import Combine` for me :p

Comment: @George "But it's using SwiftUI, so Combine is already imported by SwiftUI" that's what I originally thought, but sometimes you still need to manually import it yourself. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67353167/14351818)